# Julia VS code debugger gets stuck

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, julia, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a Julia package I'm maintaining (see test script: https://github.com/PierreBarrat/TreeKnit.jl/blob/master/test/splitgraph/3solutions/test.jl)

When I run the debugger, it always gets stuck at the same function (`SplitGraph.sa_opt`).

The code I'm running completes really fast, in around 300 milliseconds when not using a debugger. It seems to work alright, there's no error, so I'm totally confused what's happening.

I'm using the default Julia extension for VS code, and everything is still set to default.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem and figured out a solution? I checked Stack Overflow and Julia discourse for this problem but couldn't find any similar questions.

Comment: The extension maintainers want you to report on GitHub, https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues

Comment: @AParker Have you checked whether the debugger times out?